# Dynamically attach checked event on checkBox using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox, checked

i have a checkBox generated at runtime using a for loop, now i want to attach checked event for each checkboxes... how to implement the same in jquery.

i am using tables.. td.. for adding checkBox.

```
<script>
var genTable = "<table border='1' style='border-collapse:collapse' cellpadding='5' width='100%'><thead><tr><td><input type='checkBox' id='mainCheck' /></td><td>ID</td><td>ArticleTitle</td><td>ArticleDate</td></tr></thead>";
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    if (result[i].IsImageAvailable == "TRUE") {
                        iChecked = "";
                    }
                    else {
                        iChecked = "disabled = disabled";
                    }
                    genTable += "<tr><td width='2%'>
<!--Here is my checkBox on which i want to attach checked event-->
<input type='checkBox' id='chkBox" + i + "' onchange='FillSecondGrid(" + result[i].ArticleID + ")' />

</td><td width='5%'>" + result[i].ArticleID + "</td><td>" + result[i].ArticleTitle + "</td><td width='5%'>" + result[i].ArticleDate + "</td></tr>";
                }
                genTable += "</tbody></table>";
                document.getElementById("gridFirst").innerHTML = genTable;
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean the checkboxes are adding to page after the initial page load (AJAX)?

Comment: i have updated my question with the code... hope it help you guys to resolve my issue, and yes this is getting called on document.ready Jquery event.

Comment: In newer versions of JQuery (>1.7) use .on() instead (http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're generating the checkbox markup in `script` tags, you can just add the `onchange` event after the checkbox generation:

```
<script>
  // .. checkbox generation here ..
  $('table').find('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () { /* do things on change here */ });
</script>
```

Or, alternatively, just use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on all checkbox elements on document ready:

```
$(function () {
  // on document ready..
  $('table input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() { /* do things on change here */ });
}
```

The `.on` method will catch any new checkboxes created after document ready (as well as those already present) and attach your `onchange` event.

Comment: for future viewer .live is remove since jquery 1.9 just change to .on and that will do.

Answer (score 1):

No answers here have passed the event in, which you need to find out if the checkbox is checked or not. Here is a cross browser snippet that attaches the event to all the check boxes that are a child of the given element and works out when the checkbox is clicked if it is on or off.

```
var checkboxes = $(element).find("input[type=\"checkbox\"]");
$(checkboxes).change(function (event) {
    // These two lines compensate for getting the event and checkbox when in ie.
    if (!event) { var event = window.event; }
    var checkbox = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if (checkbox.checked)
        alert("Checkbox is checked");
    else
        alert("Checkbox is not checked");
});
```

I don't think the two ie compensating lines are actually needed for jQuery events, but useful to put there so that your code will work with none jQuery events as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use live() for that. Here is an example (please check for syntax etc.):

```
$('.someclassforyourcheckbox').live('change', function(){//do your stuff})
```

Answer (score 0):

add a class to your checkbox

```
<input class="dynChk" type='checkBox' id='chkBox" + i + "' onchange='FillSecondGrid(" + result[i].ArticleID + ")' />
```

and then use `delegate` or `live`

```
$("table").delegate(".dynChk",'change',function(){
//your code
});
```

with `live`

```
$(".dynChk").live("change",function(){
//your code
});
```